# How I can switch the mobile version to view full website..? But i have this code on my index page

Tags: mobile, web, http-redirect

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <=600)
    {
      document.location = "http://www.manyweb.com/" 
        }    

    </script>   -->
```

How to redirect mobile website to desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear question, but I'd suggest using something like jQuery and instead use

```
$(document).width();
```

You can use debug (firebug or else) to check if your code works